# NullPointerException при использование Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно, использую Retrofit2 и получаю такую ошибку: `"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'retrofit2.Call com.example.com.xxx.TechNewsApi.articles(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"`

Класс App:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static TechNewsApi service;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(TechNewsApi.class);

    }
}
```

Интерфейс:

```
public interface TechNewsApi {
    @GET("{articleId}.json?print=pretty")
    Call<List<Article>> articles(@Path("articleId") String articleId);
}
```

Активити, где вызывается Retrofit:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

   // в этой строчке происходит ошибка
        Call<List<Article>> call = App.service.articles("1");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Article>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Article>> call, Response<List<Article>> response) {
                Log.e("Retrofit respoce: ", response.body().toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Article>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Something went wrong:", t.getMessage());
            }

        });

    }
```

}

Comment: ваше `App` в манифесте прописано?

Comment: @ermak0ff Упс, нет

Comment: @ermak0ff Вы правы, проблема была в этом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пропишите ваш класс `App` в манифесте:

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    ...
</application>
```